# Logwatch sends me 2 copies of yesterday's server activity, why?

Tags: fedora, logwatch, cron.daily

I use Logwatch to track what is going on on one of my Fedora 11 boxes. Since updating it from an older Fedora release I now get 2 copies of the same information to my inbox. I cannot find where this might be getting duplicated. I was assuming it might be in the cron.daily and/or cron.logwatch but I am not sure what I should be looking for with regard to a duplicate being created.

Comment: No bounty will be started for this, I have followed the instructions below and they do not reveal a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the **[anacron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron)** rpm from my system and problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just `grep -r logwatch /etc/cron*` and see if there are two files talking about logwatch.

Comment: Appears to be only this one /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there aren't two instances of cron running. The following command should only output one pid.

```
pgrep -l cron
```

Comment: Nope, only 1 pid for crond